# pyenvの環境を同じマシンの複数ユーザーで共有したい

Tags: python, linux, pyenv

Linux初心者です。AmazonLinuxを使用して勉強しています。

Pyenvをec2-userだけではなく、rootやec2-user2、ec2-user3…でも使いたいと考えています。
その場合、どういう構成でやるのがLinuxの作法にあっているのでしょうか？
rootでインストールし、/usr/local/.pyenvにインストールし、
developmentユーザーグループにrootとec2-userを追加しましたが、
pyenvの3.5.2と一緒に入ってくるpipのパーミッションが755になっていましたので、
インストールしたユーザでしか使えないようでした。
pyenvで新しいバージョンをインストールするごとにpipなどの実行ファイルを775に変更するのが面倒なので何かよい方法はないでしょうか？

またここで疑問がわいたのですが、
そもそもpyenvなどの実行ファイルはインストールしたユーザーごとに管理するのが正しいのでしょうか？

--------------追記---------------------

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 538, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/test/bin/pip' -> '/tmp/pip-cvofnnvv-uninstall/usr/local/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/test/bin/pip'
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `chmod g+s pyenv`でファイルにスティッキービットを立てると、グループの権限で実行されるようになりますので、試して見てください（保証なし）。また`find /usr/local/.pyenv -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod g+ws`としてディレクトリに`chmod g+ws`するとグループの書き込み権限げ継承されるようになりますので、グループ内の誰でも追加ができるようになります

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。無事、pipの実行はできるようになりましたが、pipのインストールのコピーがうまくいかずに落ちてしまいます。うまくいく方法をご存知でしたらご教授いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

コメントいただいた方ありがとうございます。
現段階での私の調査した内容を書きます。

composerをシステムインストールできるように
pyenvをシステムインストールするものだと思っていましたが、

pyenvのgithubに書かれてあるインストール方法を見るに
https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv

```
git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
```

ホームディレクトリにインストールしています。
つまり、pyenvコマンドは共通して使うものではなく、
各ユーザ毎に管理/インストールするものなので、
複数のユーザで管理するものではない。
が現段階での結論です。

間違えているかもしれませんので引き続きご指摘 + 回答をお願いします。
よろしくお願いします。